# How to write to a StreamWriter without flush or close

Tags: vb.net, stdout, streamwriter, redirectstandardoutput

I am trying to redirect the standard output to a file for logging purpose.

```
Dim tmp As TextWriter = Console.Out  
Dim sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText("log.txt"))
Console.SetOut(sw)
Console.Write("Test")
```

but it looks like nothing get written until I call Flush() or Close() on the StreamWriter. Since the stream is going to stay open for a long time (Until the application closes), I would like the buffer to write directly to the file, otherwise it might become really big. How can I do that ?

Comment: Use a [Using Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)

Comment: wrap in using block or (vb.net equivalent)

Comment: As for now I create the StreamWriter in a constructor and I close it in its destructor so I can't wrap it in a Using block. Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your [`StreamWriter.AutoFlush`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush(v=vs.110).aspx) property to true:

> AutoFlush to true means that data will be flushed from the buffer to the stream after each write operation, but the encoder state will not be flushed